# How to deactivate vertical scrolling within a tableView cell when a chart within a cell is selected?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, tableview

I am working on an iOS-app.

I have a UITableViewController with different cells. Scrolling should be enabled because the content is larger than the phone screen. But within the last cell there is a chart view made with Charts. The functionality is, that you can select and highlight values of the chart. But if I touch the chart and tap different values (hold my finger down and move it around), not only the values are highlighted, but also the table view is scrolling. I don't want that scrolling. The Charts-cell is the last cell in the tableView, and I don't want to enable scrolling of the table view when the user touches this last cell.

I tried to disable user interaction on this cell, but this of course doesn't work, as you then cannot select values in the chart.

But as I am no expert on iOS, I don't know what else I can try to solve this problem. I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: You should not mix any scrolling related controls in UITableView. I would suggest that use UIViewController add UITableView and add chart below the UITableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add UIScrollViewDelegate to your UIViewController and try:

```
   func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    guard let lastRow = tableView.visibleCells.last else { return  }
    if tableView.visibleCells.contains(lastRow) {
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
    }   
}

func scrollViewShouldScrollToTop(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) -> Bool {

    // once the values in the chart are changed and saved, enable scrollView and use this delegate.
    // tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
    return true
}
```

I just tried this in my collectionView and it works.